# How to get a source code using github - OS X

Tags: macos, github

I am trying to get a source code for an application from github.

But i can not exactly figure out how to accomplish and set this up...

Has anyone used github before.

i am using the latest version on OS X

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does not seem to be android related; however, the simplest way to get source of a github project without knowing how to use git is to visit their page on github, and use the "downloads" button near the top right of the page.

Example of a page: https://github.com/joyent/node - notice the downloads button on the right next to the description.

If you have git installed you can clone the url provided on that page. Ex: git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git

Comment: It has to do with an Android Source Code

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the latest version, click the “Downloads” link on the repository page to receive a zip file. If you want to browse the history locally or make commits, install git and clone it:

1. Read [How to install git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide#323764) The Mac link on [Git’s home page](http://git-scm.com/) appears to link to an easy installer.
2. On the main page for a repository on github, there is a URL of the form `https://github.com/username/repository.git`. In the terminal, use the command `git clone https://github.com/…` to clone it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Macs but on Linux its, git clone (git addy). which will create a clone of the project.  If you're using eclipse, check out egit. Also read the docs on github to understand what git is and how to use it.